# How to convert this to Linq?

Tags: linq, for-loop

I got another Linq problem.. Because I'm not really sure if there is another way to do this. Here is what I want to convert:

```
class ID
{
 public string name {get; set;}
 public int id {get; set;}
}

ID[] num1 = new ID[2] { {"david",1} , {"mark",2} };
ID[] num2 = new ID[3] { {"david",1} , {"david",2} };

for(int i = 0; i < num1.Length; i++)
{
 for(int j = 0; j < num2.Length; j++)
 {
  if(num1.name.Equals(num2.name) && num1.num == num2.num)
  {
   Console.Writeline("name: " + num1.name + " id: " + num1.id);
   //Do something
   break; //to avoid useless iterations once found
  }
 }
}
```

It's not a perfect code, but hopefully it captures what I want to do. Currently I am implementing this in Linq like such:

```
var match = 
from a in num1
from b in num2
where (a.name.Equals(b.name) && a.num == b.num)
select a;
//do something with match
```

I'm pretty new to Linq so I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it or is there a much more "simpler" way. Since it seems like I'm just converting it to linq but essentially does the same code.

Thank you!

Comment: what are num1 and num2? You define them as instances of Number1, but you try using them as arrays or some kind collections (calling Length on them....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linq code you wrote is already on the right track to solve the problem, though it is not the only way to solve it.

Instead of using a `where` clause, you could override [the `Equals` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) on the class, or [implement an `IEqualityComaprer<Number>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx). Then you could use [the `Intersect` Linq method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342276.aspx).

Something like this:

```
public class Number
{
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        var otherAsNumber = other as Number;
        return otherAsNumber != null
            && (otherAsNumber.Name == null
                ? this.Name == null
                : otherAsNumber.Name.Equals(this.Name)
            )
            && otherAsNumber.Num == this.Num
            ;
    }

    // ...
}

// ...

var result = num1.Intersect(num2);

foreach(var item in result)
{
    // Do something
}
```

This of course assumes that you've fixed your code so that it compiles, and so that `num1` and `num2` refer to collections of `Number` classes, instead of individual `Number` instances. There are a lot of problems in the code you wrote, so I'll leave fixing that problem to you.

Comment: Thanks Merlyn! I forgot a crucial part, the break; inside the 2nd for loop. I use that to cancel out unnecessary iterations once it finds what it needs.

Is there a way to implement that break; in linq? I want to use any, but I am having a problem due to the Number class having 2 properties which need to be mapped to each other (ex. {"david", 1} {"mark", 2}}.

I have edited the code a bit for completion.

Comment: `Intersect` then `First` should make it so the `foreach` does lazy evaluation, and breaks on the first found match. Maybe :) The perf shouldn't matter that much though unless you're talking about huge datasets or super-high-concurrency web services or something along those lines.